# Convergence of Sequence in Fixed Point Topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $X$ be infinite set. Fix a point $x\in X$ and define a nonempty set $U\subseteq X$ to be open if and only if $x\in U$. I want to know if $(x_n)$ is sequence in $X$ such that no $n$ satisfies $x_n=p$, whether $(x_n)$ converges or not. If $(x_n)$ is eventually constant sequence, say equals to $a\neq p$, then this converges to $a$ since any neighborhood of $a$ is subset of $X$ which contains $a$ and $p$. Now if $(x_n)$ does not become eventually constant, is it correct that it does not converge since for any $x_0\in X$, we can take $\{x_0,x\}$ as neighborhood of $x_0$ so this set does not contain all tails of $(x_n)$?

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity. Fix $0\in X$. We define a topology on $X$ to be $\tau =\{U\in 2^{X}-\{\varnothing\} : 0\in U \}$ $\cup \{ \varnothing \}$.

Fix $p\in X$. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\neq p$ for all $n$.

Is $(x_n)_n$ convergent?

Look at $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. As you surely already know, $\frac{1}{n}\neq 0$ for all $n$.

Assume $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow x$. So, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$  that contains $0$ and $x$ must contain $\frac{1}{n}$ for all large $n$.

Specifically, $\{0,x\}$ must contain all $\frac{1}{n}$ for large $n$.